# Is there a way to work without collections in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Sql has something like

```
select * from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) numbers(number)
```

or

```
SELECT 10 + 15;
```

which works without a table.

So, is there a way to work with some dummy data (maybe give some integer array [1,2,3] and filter which are lower than 2), or give 2 numbers and get the sum?

Comment: Have you checked out [$documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/documents/)?

Comment: I guess it's added in newer versions.

Comment: `$documents` was added in in version 5.1. Current version is 7.0

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. mongoDB has integrated javascript engine , so you can do anything that javascript can do  , example:

   ```
   mongos> (2+2)
   4
   mongos>
   ```
2. If you need to use custom variables during documents aggregation processing , you can do using the [$let](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.2/reference/operator/aggregation/let/#mongodb-expression-exp.-let) operation , example:

   ```
   db.collection.aggregate([
   {
   $project: {
    z: {
   $let: {
     vars: {
       x: 10,
       y: 15
     },
     in: {
       $sum: [
         "$$x",
         "$$y"
       ]
     }
    }
   }
   }
   }
   ])
   ```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wOCfDUj2lvG)

Comment: For the 2nd option, it requires at least one document in the collection to work. Also, it is suggested to add a `{$limit: 1}` at the start of aggregation to improve performance.